# Where to easily find # of employees for a large group start-ups?

Tags: data-request, api, companies

I am looking for a free database or something else that provides the number of employees for mainly start-ups for some research. A range of Number of employees would also be helpful, but I would prefer an exact number.

I know I can find the number of employees on LinkedIn, but I am trying to do this for a large dataset, so going through every single company page, wouldn't be my preferred solution.

Does anyone have another database/solution for this? Thank a lot in advance!